# Cannot convert enum class to int using static_cast

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, enums

```
enum class TestEnum : int
{
    first,
    second
};

int main()
{
    int n = static_cast<int>(TestEnum::second);   // error
    return 0;
}
```

Build log:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"src/test.d" -MT"src/test.d" -o "src/test.o" "../src/test.cpp"
../src/test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../src/test.cpp:20:20: error: cannot convert ‘TestEnum’ to ‘int’ in initialization
```

gcc version 4.6.3

How can I convert `enum class` instance to `int`?

Comment: What is the question? BTW this compiles on GCC 4.8.1 and clang 3.3.

Comment: This should work. Consider updating your compiler, or maybe just writing your own conversion function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compile you code with `-std=c++0x` key. But the strong type enumeration `enum class` is a C++11 feature, so you'd better use the newer GCC compiler. GCC 4.7 or better is suitable, it has the `-std=c++11` command line key: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

This code works: http://ideone.com/4IQPUx

Comment: This answer confuses two issues. Whether a specific aspect of C++11 works on GCC is not directly related to the `std` flag being `C++0x` or `C++11`. It is simply a matter of when support for that feature was added, and relevant bugs fixed. There are plenty of C++11 features which worked on compiler versions that only supported the `C++0x` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your compiler to 4.7 and use -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 instead -std=c++0x.
scoped enums only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11